# Python compare value of CSV file

Tags: python, csv, bioinformatics

I have some issues to make an analysis on Python.

So i have a CSV file (tab sep). I have several sequences. For each sequence I can have the same genes. But a different value (here the TPM which is the Transcrit Per Million -> biology stuff).

For the same sequences, I want to conserve the gene which have the lowest TPM value.

Example of my data :

geneschr    start   end    Log2_TPM_DM_Moyenne

Cd74    **chr18 60949182    60949365**  4.253037

GAP6    **chr18 60949182    60949365**  10.590838

Rps14   **chr18 60949182    60949365**  12.590838

Mynn    chr3    30500160    30500343    3.409878

Cd74    chr16   96205452    96205635    6.105927

For example here :

The 3 first sequences are the same but have different annotated genes (with different TPM).

For this sequence I want to conserve the sequence with the lowest TPM value.

And sometimes I have a different sequence with the same closest annotated genes (Cd74). Which have the same TPM. Here I want to conserv the two sequences with the 2 TPM values because those are different sequence.

Desired output :

**genes**   **chr   start   end**   **Log2_TPM_DM_Moyenne**

**Cd74  chr18   60949182    60949365**  **4.253037**

**Mynn  chr3    30500160    30500343**  **3.409878**

**Cd74  chr16   96205452    96205635    6.105927**

For the 3 first sequences, only Cd74 was conserved because for this sequence it's the gene with the lowest TPM value.

The coordinates are the coordinates of my sequences, not of the genes. This sequence was annotated with the closest gene. 
Each gene have a TPM value. So I can have severel unique sequence with the same closest gene and the same TPM value and I want to keep them all. But for the same sequences with different annotated genes, i want to keep the gene with the lowest TPM value.

I hope I was clear enought, and Thanks you.

Best

Comment: Can you post the desired output for the sample input? What if `Cd74` was not the one with the lowest `TPM` value? Should the output have two `chr18`s (one `Cd74` and one `chr18` with the lowest TPM)?

Comment: What if there are two rows with the same `genes` and the same `chr`? Is this a possible scenario?

Comment: What is the significance of the asterisks? If they don't have any, please delete them.

Comment: I Edited my question to show the expected output. Thanks you.

It's not possible to have same coordinates with same genes. Because coordinates are unique sequences with the closest genes annotations.

Comment: I keep some asteriks to show the same sequence with different gene. Just want to make this clear. Don't know if it's work...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you want. But what did you try ? Are you waiting us doing your homework ? Is that why this question is downvoted ?

Anyway I would probably begin with something like that, although this not optimized neither for memory nor for CPU. This will not suit if your dataset has zillion-lines.

algorithm:
    1. keep all different values of 'start' and 'end' ;
    2. when 'start' and 'end' are the same, keep the lowest TPM

```
import csv
#initiazing
columns = ['start','end','TPM','chr','genes']
keptValues = {}
for c in columns:
    keptValues[c]=[]
################    
def add(k,r):
    for c in columns:
        form = determineFormat(c)
        k[c].append(form(r[c]))
##################
def replace(i,k,r):
    #print('debug: ',i,k,r)
    for c in columns:
        form = determineFormat(c)
        k[c][i] = form(r[c])
#################        
def determineFormat(s):
    if s=='start' or s=='end':
        form = int
    elif s=='TPM':
        form = float
    else:
        form = str
    return form
#################    
with open('bioinfo.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if int(row['start']) in keptValues['start'] :
            ind = keptValues['start'].index(int(row['start']))
            if keptValues['end'][ind]==int(row['end']):
                if keptValues['TPM'][ind]>float(row['TPM']):
                    replace(ind,keptValues,row)
            else:
                add(keptValues,row)
        else:
            add(keptValues,row)
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. i will try it.

Not at all. I didn't expect someone do my job. 

I tried something but it doesn't work and I have any other idea..

I tried to make a dict with coordinates as key but sometime it's doesn't work. I'm a beginner in Python...

Comment: no pb. I also used your example to practise pandas, which is a python module especially convenient for data analysing. probably the algorithm you need is much more easy with panda. I keep you informed

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495181/search-for-an-optimized-selection-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Thanks for the link Stephane. It's exactly what i'm looking for.

Comment: I just see that you created this post. It's really nice of you. Thanks you very much !