# search for an optimized selection in a pandas.dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

What is the most efficient way for selecting some rows in a pandas.dataframe,  containing N columns (strings, integers and floats), according to this selection:

- going through all combinations of 2 of the columns (integers).
- for each distinct combination, keep only one line (ie. all columns) with the minimum value in a third column (float)

for instance, for combinations of (titi,tutu) with the third column being tete:

```
  toto  tata  titi  tutu  tete
0    a    18   600   700   4.5
1    b    18   600   800  10.1
2    c    18   600   700  12.6
3    d     3   300   400   3.4
4    a    16   900  1000   6.0
5    a    18   600   800  10.1
6    c     3   300   400   3.0
7    a    16   900  1000   6.0
```

must give:

```
    toto  tata  titi  tutu  tete
0    a    18   600   700   4.5
1    b    18   600   800  10.1
4    a    16   900  1000   6.0
6    c     3   300   400   3.0
```

For the moment, I began with the following code:

```
import pandas
indicesToKeep = []
indicesToRemove = []
reader = pandas.read_csv('/Users/steph/work/perso/sof/test.csv')
columns = reader.columns
for i in reader['titi'].unique():
    #temp = reader[[:]].query('titi == i')#does not work !
    temp = reader.loc[(reader.titi == i),columns]
    for j in temp['tutu'].unique():
        temp2 = temp.loc[(temp.tutu == j),columns]
        minimum = min(temp2.tete)
        indicesToKeep.append(min(
                temp2[temp2.tete==minimum].index.tolist()))
################
# compute the complement of indicesToKeep
#but I don't remember the pythonic syntax
for i in range(len(reader)):
    if i not in indicesToKeep:
        indicesToRemove.append(i)
############################
reader = reader.drop(indicesToRemove)
```

note:

- I'm sure this is not optimized.
- I use the old 'loc' method because I do not know how to use 'query'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC `sort_values`+`drop_duplicates`, if you are suing pandas try to not using for loop,most of time it is slow than the vectorized method

```
df.sort_values('tete').drop_duplicates(['titi','tutu']).sort_index()
Out[583]: 
  toto  tata  titi  tutu  tete
0    a    18   600   700   4.5
1    b    18   600   800  10.1
4    a    16   900  1000   6.0
6    c     3   300   400   3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group by the two columns `titi` and `tutu` and then get the row index of the min value of the third row `tete`. After that is completed, it is a simple matter of looking up the rows.

```
df.loc[df.groupby(["titi", "tutu"])["tete"].idxmin()]
```

This returns the output

```
  toto  tata  titi  tutu  tete
6    c     3   300   400   3.0
0    a    18   600   700   4.5
1    b    18   600   800  10.1
4    a    16   900  1000   6.0
```

which is the desired output as above.

The groupby will ensure that all possible combinations of the 2 columns are preserved.

Comment: Much easier solution. I prefer this solution more! +1